# Track Redirect URL Status (Success, Reject)

Tags: php, url, redirect, phpmyadmin

hope you have been doing well.

I am working on a system and stuck on a point.

I am trying to track URL status. Like There is a simple URL abc.com and i use redirection xyz.com for abc.com Now when user will open xyz.com then url will be automatically redirect towards abc.com, now actual problem started.

At abc.com user will fill a form (it could be any like signup form). When user fill the form and submit then abc.com should redirect towards third website qwe.com/success or qwe.com/reject

In that case i want to know the final status of URL abc.com that final redirection result was success r reject.

Please any one know any thing about this problem then please let me know as soon as possible.

I will be very thankful to you.

I know how to make a redirect url for abc.com to xyz.com but do not know how to track final redirection result.

Comment: How are you attempting to redirect? That is important information to have to be able to help you.

Comment: Actually i am totally confused

Comment: I want to add a ID at the end of URL like abc.com?id=01 and id=02 and soon and want t track every links for specific id